# C++ compiler couldn't derive a right type from iterator

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following function:

```
template <typename Iterator> 
void merge(Iterator begin, Iterator middle, Iterator end) {
    std::vector<T> first(begin, middle), second(middle, end);

    auto i1 = first.begin();
    auto i2 = second.begin();

    while (begin != end) {
        if (i2 == second.end() || *i1 < *i2) {
            *begin = *i1;
            ++i1;
        } else {
            *begin = *i2;
            ++i2;
        }   
        ++begin;
    }   
}
```

But when I try to use it:

```
int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
merge(data, data + 4, data + 8);
```

I get a error:

```
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
```

How can I define the merge function right without explicit specifying of the T type?

Comment: The using of std::vector has the same result.

Comment: @digi_abhshk, Pointers are random-access iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is compiler supposed to guess what `T` is? You neither provided any context to deduce it from nor did you explicitly tell it (in any case, T would need to be declared in template parameter list, `like template<typename T, typename Iterator>`).

I'd use [`iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) here:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type T;
std::vector<T> first(begin, middle), second(middle, end);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::iterator_traits` to extract the type you need instead of having `T` being a template argument (which the error is really hinting at, despite your code):

```
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> first(begin, middle), second(middle, end);
```